# I get "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs' " when I execute the below code

Tags: django, django-forms

I get a type error when my form tries to execute

```
username = forms.CharField(label='User name', max_length=100,
                                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

        email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailField(attrs={'class': "form-control my-input"}), label="Enter Email")

        password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control my-input"}),
                     label="Enter Password",)
        password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control my-input"}),
                                    label="Confirm Password")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forms.EmailField` is a field not a widget, you need to use `forms.EmailInput`

```
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(...))
```